# Why will the scanner not pick up my year variable without a / at the end?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

The user is entering a date in the format XX/XX/XXXX and I use a delimiter to pick out the integers in the input, but I can't figure out how to get the year variable without placing another / at the end of the input. How do I go about getting that year variable?

Thanks in advance

```
package formatting_problem;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class DateFormatter {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer day = 0;
    Integer month = 0;
    Integer year = 0;
    Integer test = null;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("/");
    System.out.println("Enter a date in the format XX/XX/XXXX to be formatted to Month Day,Year");
    while (input.hasNext()){
        month = input.nextInt();
        day = input.nextInt();
        year = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> How do I go about getting that year variable?

You can just use `String.split()`:

```
String tokens[] = input.split("/");      //where input is a String
int month = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
int day = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
int year = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
```

**Note**: You can just use the primitive datatype `int` instead of their wrapper class `Integer`.

---

To answer your question, that is because the delimiter you assigned is only a forward slash. In Java, by default, newline characters are also one of the delimiters. However, in your redefinition of the delimiter, it was omitted.

To fix it, include the newline character as well:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("/|\\n");
```

You may also remove your while loop, and just:

```
int month = input.nextInt();
int day = input.nextInt();
int year = input.nextInt();
```